# Limit of Maxvalue function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can i compute this limit

${ G }_{ n }=max(0,n-{ 2n }^{ 2 }\left| x-\frac { 1 }{ 2n }  \right| )$
for $x\quad \epsilon \quad [0,1]$ and $\quad lim\quad n->\infty $

and show after that $\int { G_{ n }\rightarrow \int { G }  } $ with $G=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { G }_{ n } } $

Could you give me a hint on how to compute the limit.

Comment: Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing  ( n - 2${n^2}$|x - $\frac{1}{2n}$| )

as n is tending to  ${\infty}$, it will be positive

So our equation becomes

= n - 2${n^2}$|$\frac{2nx - 1}{2n}$|

= n - n |2nx - 1|     ..... (canceling 2n on numerator and denominator)

Now we see that element inside modulus tends to ${\infty}$ as n tends to ${\infty}$

This means that our entire term tends to negative value. Hence G would always be zero (as max of 0 and a negative number is 0)